# How to intercept QProgressDialog cancel click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6, qprogressdialog

I have a standard QProgressDialog with a cancel button. If/When the user clicks the cancel button, I don't want the dialog to immediately hide, instead I would prefer to disable the cancel button and perform some clean-up work, and then close the QProgressDialog once I'm sure this work is complete.
How to I intercept the current function?

From the docs it seems like I should be overwriting:

`PySide.QtGui.QProgressDialog.cancel()`

> Resets the progress dialog. PySide.QtGui.QProgressDialog.wasCanceled()
> becomes true until the progress dialog is reset. The progress dialog
> becomes hidden.

I've tried subclassing this method but it doesn't even seem to be called when I click the cancel button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the button of the dialog you have to get a reference to it. Since it is a basic QPushButton, you can use [`findChild()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild):

```
dialog = QProgressDialog(self)
cancelButton = dialog.findChild(QPushButton)
cancelButton.setEnabled(False)
```

Consider that disabling a button that would *never* get enabled is annoying from the UX point of view, so a better choice would be to *not* show it at all, and [`setCancelButton()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html#setCancelButton) explains how to do it:

> If `nullptr` is passed, no cancel button will be shown.

In python terms, `nullptr` means `None`:

```
dialog = QProgressDialog(self)
dialog.setCancelButton(None)
```

Unfortunately, this won't prevent the user to cancel the dialog by closing it or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

This is valid for *any* QDialog, and, to properly avoid that, subclassing is the better choice: you need to prevent *rejecting* the dialog (the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key) **and** the *close event*. While they have similar results, they are handled in different ways.

Overriding `reject()` (and doing nothing) prevents any action that would trigger a rejection (cancelling), including pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Overriding the `closeEvent()` requires an extra step: you have to ensure that the event is [`spontaneous()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#spontaneous) (triggered by the system - normally, the user presses the close button of the window), and eventually ignore that. This is necessary as you might need to call `close()` or `accept()` to *actually* close the dialog upon completing the process.

```
class NonStopProgressDialog(QtWidgets.QProgressDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setCancelButton(None)

    def reject(self):
        pass

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if event.spontaneous():
            event.ignore()
```

Note that there is no direct way to know if the *spontaneous* close event is directly triggered by the user (trying to close the window), or the system (while shutting down).

Also note that if you *do* need to close the dialog programmatically, you either call `accept()`, or you call the base implementation, which allows you to get the proper return value from the dialog's `reject()`:

```
    def rejectNoMatterWhat(self):
        super().reject()
```

Finally, if, for any reason, you still need the cancel button, you have to disconnect its signals.

In general, this might do the work:

```
dialog = QProgressDialog(self)
cancelButton = dialog.findChild(QPushButton)
cancelButton.disconnect()
```

But the above would disconnect *any* signal to *any* slot, and there are some cases for which this should be avoided.
We know from [the sources](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/dialogs/qprogressdialog.cpp#n403) that the `clicked` signal is actually connected to the `canceled()` slot, so a better solution would be to do the following instead:

```
dialog = QProgressDialog(self)
cancelButton = dialog.findChild(QPushButton)
cancelButton.clicked.disconnect(self.canceled)
```

Since you may need to be notified about that in the parent/main class, a more appropriate solution would be to create a custom signal in the subclass used above:

```
class NonStopProgressDialog(QtWidgets.QProgressDialog):
    userCancel = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cancelButton = self.findChild(QPushButton)
        cancelButton.clicked.disconnect(self.canceled)
        cancelButton.clicked.connect(
            lambda: cancelButton.setEnabled(False))
        cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.userCancel)

    def reject(self):
        pass

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if event.spontaneous():
            event.ignore()

class SomeWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def showProgress(self):
        self.progressDialog = NonStopProgressDialog(self)
        self.progressDialog.userCancel.connect(self.stopSomething)
        # ...

    def stopSomething(self):
        self.progressDialog.setCancelButtonText('Please wait')
        # do something...
```

Comment: This is has helped me but I'm not 100% there yet. I've figured out that if I leave the Cancel pushbutton in place, using Esc or clicking the Cancel button doesn't seem to trigger the overwritten `closeEvent`. If I eliminate the Cancel pushbutton using `Dialog.setCancelButton(None)`, using Esc will allow me to enter the overwritten `closeEvent`. Since I would like to keep the Cancel pushbutton in place, and only disable it when I'm processing things before closing the dialog, is there a way of disconnecting the normal cancel function so I can always get to my `closeEvent`.

Comment: So, you want to keep the cancel button visible, and change its behavior when it's enabled and then clicked?

Comment: Yes. Once it is clicked I want to keep the ProgressDialog visible until I perform some clean-up work in the background. This is just to let the user know something is still going on.

Comment: @ZacharyTaylor see the update.

Comment: Beautiful, this does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!